# How to print the sum of the number of times a certain integer returns?

Tags: python-3.x

Heres the code:
I want to be able to print something like **"Buy! = ???"** or **"Sell! = ???"** or **"Hold! = ???"**.

```
list_A = []
list_B = []

num_sells = 0
num_buys = 0
num_holds = 0


for x in range(10000):
    list_A.append(np.random.randint(0,10))
    list_B.append(np.random.randint(0,10))


    if list_A[x] > list_B[x]:
        num_buys += 1
        cprint("Buy!", 'green', attrs=['bold', 'reverse', 'blink'], file=sys.stderr)


    elif list_A[x] < list_B[x]:
        num_sells += 1
        cprint("Sell!", 'red', attrs=['bold', 'reverse', 'blink'], file=sys.stderr)

    else:
        num_holds += 1
        cprint("Hold!", attrs=['bold', 'reverse', 'blink', 'dark'], file=sys.stderr)
```

Recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you put more clarity on what do you mean by "sum of the number of times a certain number returns" ?

Comment: Yeah so, when I run this code I recieve a 10,000 word response with the words "Buy!", "Sell!" or "Hold!". I want to print the amount of times the word "Buy!" comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Well then just print the answer outside the loop. If I'm getting your doubt correctly.

```
list_A = []
list_B = []

num_sells = 0
num_buys = 0
num_holds = 0


for x in range(10000):
    list_A.append(np.random.randint(0,10))
    list_B.append(np.random.randint(0,10))


    if list_A[x] > list_B[x]:
        num_buys += 1



    elif list_A[x] < list_B[x]:
        num_sells += 1


    else:
        num_holds += 1

cprint("Buy!", 'green', attrs=['bold', 'reverse', 'blink'], file=sys.stderr)
cprint("Sell!", 'red', attrs=['bold', 'reverse', 'blink'], file=sys.stderr)
cprint("Hold!", attrs=['bold', 'reverse', 'blink', 'dark'], file=sys.stderr)
```

Like the above.